# Positioning text on window resizing

Tags: html, css

How can text in `<p>` tag be positioned dynamically while window size changed.

Here is mine CSS:

```
.map_text {
    position: relative;
    font-size: .9em;
    font-style: italic;
    width: 650px;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 50px;    
    left: 255px;
    bottom: 37px;
}
```

I have some sort of container that my `.map_text` element is put in. It is positioned correctly. When I try to change my browsers window size I have overlapped `.map_text` element that text is out of the container's bound.

**UPDATE**: Here is mine HTML:

```
<div id="some_dropbox">
   <form id="someForm">
      <p>Some text</p>
   </form>
   <form id="some_form_id"><input id="save_id" value="Save" disabled="disabled" type="submit" /></form>
   <div id="columns_dropbox">
      <form id="some_columns_form_id">
     <p>
        Select Name: 
        <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
        <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
        </select>
     </p>
      </form>
      <p id="map_text_id" class="map_text error">Some realy realy realy realy realy realy realy realy realy realy realy realy realy long text</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please show relevant html too...

Comment: which direction is .map_text overflowing?

Comment: It overlaps it container over the right board.

Comment: Here's a fiddle demonstrating the OP's code: http://jsfiddle.net/JKuuf/

Answer (score 0):

add     `float: right;`
is this what you are after:
http://jsfiddle.net/J2VAY/1/

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for me. Maybe _float: left_ is better here but indeed text will not be enough big by width, i.e. when container will be smaller text will be smaller too but for this I should match it _width_ parameter and prevent it dynamically resizing in case there are more space for text rendering.